# Group the response in Months interval depending on value of rates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using Rails 3.
I am calling REST API and getting the response in following format.

```
[{"id"=>"1", "rate"=>13.0, "month"=>1, "year"=>2012},
{"id"=>"2", "rate"=>13.0, "month"=>2, "year"=>2012},
{"id"=>"3", "rate"=>13.0, "month"=>3, "year"=>2012},
{"id"=>"4", "rate"=>16.0, "month"=>4, "year"=>2012},
{"id"=>"5", "rate"=>16.0, "month"=>5, "year"=>2012},
{"id"=>"6", "rate"=>13.0, "month"=>6, "year"=>2012},
{"id"=>"7", "rate"=>18.0, "month"=>7, "year"=>2012},
{"id"=>"8", "rate"=>18.0, "month"=>8, "year"=>2012},
{"id"=>"9", "rate"=>18.0, "month"=>9, "year"=>2012},
{"id"=>"10", "rate"=>20.0, "month"=>10, "year"=>2012},
{"id"=>"11", "rate"=>20.0, "month"=>11, "year"=>2012},
{"id"=>"12", "rate"=>20.0, "month"=>12, "year"=>2012},
{"id"=>"13", "rate"=>13.0, "month"=>1, "year"=>2013},
{"id"=>"14", "rate"=>13.0, "month"=>2, "year"=>2013}]
```

The use cases is I need to club the period of months depending on the value of Rates on front end.

E.g. I am having the rate as "13.0" for months 01-2012, 02-2012, 03-2012, 06-2012. 
On front end I need to show only two rows which says
1. Row. Start Date "01-2012" and End Date "03-2012".
2. Row. Start Date "06-2012" and End Date "06-2012".

I am trying by grouping the response on the basis of "rates" and "year". After that I am ordering on that result by month.

Still I need to check the each and every object and then club them.

```
def group_dates(response)
      group_by_rate_and_year = response.group_by { |resp| resp.values_at("rate", "year") }
      group_by_rate_and_year.each{|gbyk,gbyv|
          sort_by_months = gbyv.sort_by{|month| month["month"]}
          sort_by_months.each do |s_month|

          end
        }
    end
```

Can anyone suggest some solution to this problem?

Thanks,
Tushar

Comment: hm, should `{"id"=>"13", "rate"=>13.0, "month"=>1, "year"=>2013},
{"id"=>"14", "rate"=>13.0, "month"=>2, "year"=>2013}` also be in the output?..

Comment: Hi, are you still interested in getting an answer? Have you solved the issue?